# How do you prove the following vector identity

Tags: vector-analysis, differential

Hi I am currently revising for an exam and have seen a question from a past paper and I am not sure the best way to go about it, do I change the $\nabla$ $\phi$ and $\nabla$ $\psi$ to vector fields?And then use

$\nabla$ $\bullet$ ($F$ $\times$ $G$)= ($\nabla$$\times$ $F$)$\bullet$ $G$ -$F$$\bullet$($\nabla$ $\times$$G$)?

Here is the equation to prove;

$\nabla$ $\bullet$($\nabla$ $\phi$ $\times$$\nabla$ $\psi$)$f$)=($\nabla$ $\phi$ $\times$$\nabla$ $\psi$)$\bullet$$\nabla$$f$.

Where $f$,$\phi$ and $\psi$ are smooth scalar fields and $F$ & $G$ are vector fields. We may use other differential identities stated at the top of the paper( The usual 7). Any help would be appreciated as its tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\nabla \phi$ and $\nabla \psi$ are already vector fields. (You don't need to think about "changing them into vector fields"!)

And $\nabla \phi \times \nabla \psi$ is *also* a vector field!

Therefore, a good way to start is to apply the general vector identity $$\nabla . (f\mathbf A) = \nabla f.\mathbf A + f(\nabla . \mathbf A)  . $$
to show that
$$ \nabla . (f(\nabla \phi \times \nabla \psi)) = \nabla f. (\nabla \phi \times \nabla \psi) + f (\nabla . (\nabla \phi \times \nabla \psi)).$$

Having done this, you could then try to use the vector identity $$ \nabla . (\mathbf A \times \mathbf B) = (\nabla \times \mathbf A) . \mathbf B - \mathbf A . (\nabla \times \mathbf B)$$ to show that

$$\nabla . (\nabla \phi \times \nabla \psi) = (\nabla \times \nabla \phi) . \nabla \psi - \nabla \phi . (\nabla \times \nabla \psi),$$
which is zero, because the curl of a gradient is always zero.

You can find a full list of vector identities [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Operator_notations).